# No suitable driver found error for odbc, db2

Tags: java, sql, odbc, db2, driver

I'm trying to connect to a remote database using the following java code, but I get an error saying no suitable driver found.

```
DriverManager.getConnection("odbc:db2://url:port/dbname");
 Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution...I didn't add the JAR files for the driver.

Comment: This is only part of the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Two comments:

1. You have to load the driver first, before trying to use it

2. If I am not mistaken, the driver you are loading is a **JDBC** driver for DB2 UDB, not **ODBC**. The connection URL for it is "jdbc:db2//host:port/database"

So your code should look something like this:

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://host_or_ip_address:port/dbname");
```

Comment: How exactly do I load the driver?

Comment: Loading the driver=loading driver class, i.e. `Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");`

Answer (score 0):

You should add jar files of db2cc.jar,db2jcc_license_cu.jar and db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar files into your classpath location and these jar files held in your db2 installation directory location under java folder you got the above jar files